# How to access site from outside, hosted on IIS?

Tags: iis, windows-7, web-server, hosting

I hosted a web site on IIS (Windows 7 Professional) running on port 81 because I have Apachi installed on port 80.
I can easily access site from http://localhost:81/testsite on server machine

I can remote desktop my server from out side by address like **58.124.112.55:3381**

Now I want to access my site from out side but I could not access it by

http://58.124.112.55:81/testsite

Please tell me that how could I access it from outside. What could be the live link.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to configure your WAN firewall to allow port 81 inbound from the outside, same as has been done with port 3381 for remote desktop.

Comment: can I configure port 3381 for IIS so that have not to do this whole process?

Comment: Well, you'd mess up your Remote desktop ability, and would have to disable that or change its port first.  But yes, in theory you could adjust IIS to listen on port 3381 for the website.

Comment: Thanks I set configured it to 81 ... and working perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

bind your site to an ip ex(90)
in firewall create an exception for that port allowing all incoming traffic to it,
in your router(if pc is connected to any) type in browser 192.168.1.1 or 192.168.2.1 and in advance settings (netgear) or vhost (belkin) reserve an internal ip so if the pc is restarted it will always have the same ip adress(162.168.1.10) and open the port (90) in this case and attach it to the pc internal ip, once this is done, check your public ip (112.172.110.95) example of a public ip, then search in your browser 112.172.110.95:90 and it will connect to your site without the need of a domain name.
please note that if your public ip changes you have to type that ip but always the same port, that's why is better to have an static IP or a non IP account.

Comment: This answer is a little confusing (you could have used the IPs the OP gave), and I am not sure it necessarily applies to the OP's situation - you seem to be describing port-forwarding. It would also help if you could format your answer a bit, to make it easier to read.